# Is it possible to change the eclipse title

Tags: eclipse

Which file to edit to change the Eclipse IDE title: "Java - Eclipse SDK" to something of my own, say "Test - SDK"

Also which file contains the contents of About dialog box under help menu. Is it possible to edit it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the About dialog there are two means of customizatoin:

1. [An API](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/about/package-summary.html?resultof=%22%61%62%6f%75%74%22%20%22%64%69%61%6c%6f%67%22%20)
2. [Product Branding](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/product_editor/branding.htm?resultof=%22%61%62%6f%75%74%22%20%22%64%69%61%6c%6f%67%22%20)

Answer (score 77):

1- Try  window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Worspacename (shown in window title)

2- idk :/

Comment: I don't understand why THIS is not the accepted answer!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  This is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the "-showLocation" option as well.
This needs to be used in the startup paramater.

I am using Windows and I modified my Eclipse shortcut to have the parameter (In Eclipse shortcut properties > Shortcut tab > Target textbox)

```
C:\Eclipse3.7\eclipse.exe -showLocation
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is "branding".

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html