# Changing eclipse window's name

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, title, titlebar

I'm working on a project for which I have one eclipse workspace. However, there are three folders inside this workspace, each of which have similar filenames.
Corresponding to these three folders, I have three eclipse windows open, displaying the files in each.

However, since the filenames are similar and the files are ordered the same way across all windows, I can't immediately tell which folder's window I'm looking at right now. Technically, this can be achieved by looking at the title bar as shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

But using that identifier is sub optimal as I have to search for the folder name in the middle of that string.
It would be much more preferable if I could write a dedicated string to the title of the window, which would help me identify the folder, whose files are contained in that window.

I am aware that I can set a custom "workspace" identifying string in the window, but since that's at a workspace level, setting that string affects all three windows and therefore does not function at the window level.

Is setting such a string even possible? How might I accomplish this?

**Tech Specs**:

1. Eclipse Juno
2. Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

Comment: Is this question not answered by  [Is it possible to change the eclipse title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664917)?

Comment: @jwpat7: My question is NOT answered by that link. I need window-specific titles, not workspace-specific titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out of the box for eclipse that can help.  Probably going to need an eclipse plugin to customize the workbench window titles in this way.  One solution would be to write your [own Eclipse plugin](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) that would do exactly what you need which would involve just grabbing the various workbench window shells and based on your own needs setting the Text to whatever title you need.

However writing a new Eclipse plugin maybe to heavyweight for you.  One option would be to install a scripting environment into your Eclipse environment.  <strike>I looked at [Eclipsescript](http://eclipsescript.org/) but I don't think it is going to give you access to the WorkbenchWindow object you need to get the active shell to change the title.  Something more like Eclipse Monkey is what you need.</strike>  However, [Eclipse monkey](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/introduction-scripting-eclipse) is discontinued.  Perhaps [Groovy Monkey](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Monkey).  This way you could write a groovy script that you could execute once you have Eclipse running and it could modify the titles for you and much more.

With groovy monkey, the script you would need to execute would be:

```
window.getShell().setText( 'Custom shell text' )
```

**Update** Following up from a comment I looked again and [EclipseScript](http://eclipsescript.org/) is what you need and it is drop-dead simple as well.

1. Install EclipseScript from this [updatesite](http://eclipsescript.org/updates/).
2. Create a new file like `customWindowTitles.eclipse.js`
3. Add a line like: `Packages.org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setText('Foo');`
4. Execute the script with `Alt+R` if you are on windows.

Comment: It's actually possible with EclipseScript - just use the one-liner: "Packages.org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setText("Custom title");"

Comment: Thanks for following up, I will try it out and update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) you are using an X Windows System computer (based on path shown in the title bar in the question).  If so, your window manager should have a mechanism for changing window titles.

The following illustrates a slightly-clunky method that may serve if you don't find a good window-manager-specific route.

```
tini ~ > wmctrl -l |grep Eclipse
0x06400080  1 tini Java - Eclipse
0x06401d89  1 tini Java - Eclipse 

tini ~ > wmctrl -ir 0x06400080 -N 'oneForEach'

tini ~ > wmctrl -l |grep 0x0640
0x06400080  1 tini oneForEach
0x06401d89  1 tini Java - Eclipse
```

Note, "wmctrl is a UNIX/Linux command line tool to interact with an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager", as described at [tomas.styblo.name](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) and in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl).  Package managers for several linux distributions can install it.

`wmctrl -l` lists all the managed windows.  `wmctrl -ir 0x06400080 -N 'oneForEach'` changes the long name (in the window title bar) of the window identified by the indicated hexadecimal number.

Comment: I just tried this. I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) and just installed `wmctrl` through macports. Sadly, `wmctrl -l` gives no results, so I can't grep anything

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, bummer!  I suggest asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com about changing window titles.  I looked briefly at  [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659) but didn't see anything relevant.  BTW, does `wmctrl -m` show anything?

Comment: Thanks for the apple.SE reco. Output from `wmctrl -m`: `Name: N/A  \\
Class: N/A  \\
PID: N/A  \\
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A`