# Eclipse: Hide current filename in title bar

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm looking for a option to hide the current file name in the title bar of eclipse, since is sometimes terribly long especially when working on java projects. 
Similar there is a start up option to include the workspace in the title bar show_location.
Thanks for hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source there does not seem to be an option for this (source is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`).

The value used is actually whatever the active editor returns from `getTitleToolTip()` but again I don't see any way to change that in the Java editor.

Comment: maybe change is the wrong approach, ignore would be the right choice. Thanks for the insides any way

Comment: as greg mentions, hiding current filename may not be possible. you can, however, append a string in the title, as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8665249/3380951)